# embed video in html page and make it play any video file in local drive

Tags: html, video, browser

I want to embed video in html page sothat I can play any multimedia file from my hard drive or from a url.I tried to create a web page with

```
<video src="test.mp4" controls width="320" height="240">

</video>
```

In `chrome`,the video plays without any problem.
However,the mp4 file is not recognized in `firefox` .It displays error message- `'no video with supported format or mimetype found'.`

It so happens that most of my video files are `.mp4 or .flv` files.

If I put 
`<source src="test.flv" />`  in the video element ,then both chrome and firefox fail to show it.

So,what should I do to play `at least mp4 and flv files in both browsers`?.

Any pointers /advice most appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From Mozilla's page on [browser-supported audio/video formats](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Media_formats_supported_by_the_audio_and_video_elements):

> The MPEG container format with the H.264 video codec and either the
>   AAC audio codec or the MP3 audio codec is supported by Internet
>   Explorer and Safari. Firefox and Opera do not support the format.
>   Support for the format is deprecated in Chrome, and Chromium does not
>   support it either.
>
> The MPEG media formats are covered by patents, which are not freely
>   licensed. All the necessary licenses can be bought from MPEG LA. Since
>   H.264 is currently not a royalty free format, it is unfit for the open
>   web platform, according to Mozilla [1, 2], Google [1, 2] and Opera.

Short answer, Firefox doesn't support mp4, as it's not open source. But it does support multiple sources and will play the first one it supports.

Further, it doesn't appear that swf or flv are supported by any browsers, since they are totally Adobe and require Flash Player, but the following should work around that:

```
<video src="test.mp4" controls>
    <object data="test.flv" type="application/x-shockwave-flash">
      <param value="test.flv" name="movie"/>
    </object>
</video>
```

Be aware that the above had `.swf` file as data and value originally; I haven't tested if `.flv` will work on its own.

Comment: so ,if I want to play mp4/flv in browser , I have no option but to use something like vlcplugin?

Comment: Or convert your files to ogg or webm. I like vlc, personally.  And I'm guessing there is a way to use the `object` tag to set the player to vlc instead of defaulting to whatever the browser is set to.

Comment: And let's not forget our old pals at [`miro`](http://www.mirovideoconverter.com/)